# Do I need a Schengen visa if I have UK permanent residency?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens, residency

Me and my friends are planning on inter railing from the UK. They all have a British Citizen but I do not. I only have a PR and I have been a resident in the UK for 10 years. The question is do I still need a schengen visa? (BTW I think I do but want to make sure).

EDIT: I have an Indian Passport

Comment: Whether or not you need a Schengen depends upon what kind of passport you are travelling on and you didn't disclose this.  UK residency has nothing to do with it.  Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: Yes, you need a visa. Your status in the UK makes no difference in almost all cases, citizenship is paramount.

Comment: If you're a permanent resident and have been living in the UK for 10 years, you're probably eligible to [naturalise as a UK citizen](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/check-if-you-can-apply). You can then travel visa-free on a British passport.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you need a visa. Your immigration status in a non-Schengen country does not make any difference.